# Set default file path for any new content added to a storage drive

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, filesystems, drive

This question requires background information:

iOS (iPhone, iPad) devices can read MP4 video files from a SD Card using the `Lightning to SD Card Reader` adapter / dongle(!). The files *must* be located in a folder structure that is formatted to look like a digital camera / camcorder added the files, such as the following file path, which will look familiar to those who use Canon video cameras:

`DCIM`/`106_0607`/ `fileName (ex: MVI_0117.MP4)`

Adding a MP4 file with the correct fileName format on the root level of the SD Card will not be recognized by the iOS device.

For reference, [see this article from Benoît Guilbaud on the subject](https://benguilbaud.com/2013/01/12/ipad-tip-how-to-store-videos-on-an-sd-card/).

---

#### With that said:

I am using [a very cool device](https://teradek.com/collections/cube-family) that allows me to stream video and record the video to a SD Card. I can set the filename, however I cannot set the file recording path :(

In the absence of setting the file path, I was wondering if I can set a default file hierarchy on the disk, so that *any new file* added to the disk will be added under a defined file path?

Thank you for reading and sharing any insight.